# Is going 64-bit ubuntu is good?

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, 64-bit

Is it all right to upgrade to 64 bit 13.04 ubuntu with this specs?

My specs:

Processor: [Intel P6200](http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz)

GPU: Intel HD Graphics

RAM: 2GB

By the way I have read this : https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/version#TOC-32-bit-or-64-bit-

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu 32bit now?

Comment: Yes, yes I do .